# Ethereum Contract call methods return insufficient gas message?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

The call methods on a contract deployed to mainnet are erroring with insufficient gas messages.

```
{
  code: -32000,
  message: 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address <address> have 27795556348606292 want 420361420000000000 (supplied gas 894386)'
}
```

On Kovan network, the call methods are working fine. But on Mainnet they are returning the above.

Since call methods require no gas, I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
$ truffle(mainnet)> c = await EthText.deployed()
$ truffle(mainnet)> c.dapp_name()
```

`dapp_name` is a call method

```
contract MyContract {
  string public dapp_name = "Eth Text";
```

What would cause this error?

Comment: Hello. Have you found an answer to you question?